# When I open a modal the statusBar content is not visible

Tags: javascript, react-native, statusbar, simplemodal

I used a modal inside which I render the default statusBar by react native but when the modal opens the content of statusBar disappears and when I closed the modal it again appears.

``
Here is my code:-
[Here is my code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDTpe.jpg)

Comment: You need to paste your code into the question rather than links to images of your code.

Comment: You can decrease the opacity of the modal or reduce the height of the modal so as not to hide the status bar.